# User names - limit of offensive?

Tags: discussion

I recently flagged sha.t ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/4519059/sha-t ) as a possibly offensive user name, the flag was declined, as noted below.

> While not particularly offended, I am not sure that shat is an
>   appropriate user name for a mixed community.
>
> declined - I don't think there's really anything actionable here -
>   it's probably an abbreviated name anyway

Does this mean that the following user names are appropriate?

Cun.t - Tina Cunningham
Twa.t - Tony Twain
Shi.t - Tom Shirley

And so on. Where does the line lie? I do not wish to flag user names that are acceptable.

Comment: Clearly sha.t is a reference to the family of cryptographic hash functons.

Comment: "While not particularly offended", you felt the need to flag for mod attention... why exactly? Maybe leave the flagging to the people who are actually offended - and then have their flags declined because that's the most stupid thing anybody could be offended about.

Comment: I just checked, and yes that is an abbreviation for their real name. No offense was intended here. I think you're seeing a puppy in the clouds.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Your insinuation that puppies are offensive offends me.

Comment: There's nothing more offensive as calling someone's name 'offensive'. Especially if they are offensive only in some dialect.

Comment: I'm curious... what do you think this could misinterpreted as?

Comment: I know Tony Cunningham, and I am pretty sure that he wouldn't go by that. Mr. Twain might though.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208555/165773

Comment: I must be weird, as I don't look at the names - just the question and answer

Comment: I am offended by this name: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8272951/racistgymteacher.  Surprised SO allows it

Answer (score 17):

One word in one language is a swear word in another language, quite often. I honestly think you should not get offended so easily over names and nick names that are not clear swear words or used with malicious intent. You should err on side of caution and let something seemingly offensive slide instead of flagging somebody completely innocent just with a name that seems offensive in your language that might be an ordinary name in another.

And as I wrote in my previous post. This is is not something even worth discussing here. Being overly PC is detrimental to everybody.

Answer (score 15):

Did you know, "Fionnuala" means "white/fair shoulder". So, I have flagged your name for racism.

<sub>No, Fionnuala is obviously not racist, and "sha.t" is obviously not a swear word. Certainly not worthy of a flag.</sub>

Comment: Even "shat" is not a swear word, is it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It is, arguably. Just about.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It may be an accepted past-tense inflection of a swear word. It could also be many many other things.

Comment: Fionnuala does not mean white fair.

Comment: @Fionnuala: Yeah, not exactly. _Behind the Name: Meaning, Origin and History of the Name Fionnuala. Means "white shoulder" from Irish fionn "white, fair" and guala "shoulder". In Irish legend Fionnuala was one of the four children of Lir who were transformed into swans for a period of 900 years_. I can add the word "shoulder" if you like but it doesn't change this answer.